# Hilbert matrix code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

A Hilbert matrix is a matrix whose elements are given by:

a<sub>ij</sub>=(i+j-1)<sup>-1</sup>

So I tried to code this in python. Here is my code:

```
import math

a = int(input("Enter row"))
b = int(input("Enter column"))

def hilmat(a,b):
    li=[0]*b
    for i in range(a):
        for j in range(b):
            if(i+j>0):  
                ele=math.pow((i+j-1),-1)
                li += ele

            else:
                ele=math.pow((1-i-j),-1)
                li += ele
        j=j+1
    i=i+1

    return li


hilmat(a,b)
```

Running this throws this error:

> Float object not iterable

How do I resolve this?

Comment: the variable `li` is a list and variable `ele` is a float, so you cant add them up

Answer (score 2):

The error here arises from `li += ele`; as `li` is of type `list`, Python takes this line as an instruction to concatenate `ele` onto the end of `li`; but `ele` is a float, so this cannot be done, as it is not a list, and so an error is raised.

Since you need a list of lists, you should set `li` initially to `[[]]*b`; but in fact, to give `li` shape `[a,b]`, you want to set `li=[[]]*a`.

In `ele=math.pow((i+j-1),-1)`, you should note that as Python indices start at `0`, you may want to use `ele=math.pow((i+j+1),-1)` instead.

A more usual syntax to append something to an array is to use the `append` method.

`i=i+1`, `j=j+1` are both redundant, as the `for` loop already handles increments. In fact, they may cause errors.

`return li` should be indented with the rest of the function.

Your final function should be:

```
def hilmat(a,b):
    li=[[]]*a
    for i in range(a):
        for j in range(b):
            ele=math.pow((i+j+1),-1)
            li[i].append(ele)
    return li
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation `li += ele` attempts to extend the list `li` with the iterable `ele`. Here `ele` is not an iterable but a `float`, so you want to append it. Replace this line by.

```
li[i].append(ele)
```

Although, you can efficiently build this matrice with a single list-comprehension.

### Code

```
def hilmat(a, b):
    return [[1 / (i + j + 1) for j in range(b)] for i in range(a)]
```

### Example

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(hilmat(3, 3))
```

### Output

```
[[1.0, 0.5, 0.33],
 [0.5, 0.33, 0.25],
 [0.33, 0.25, 0.2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my first post on stackoverflow. I found above two answers quite useful.

Here is my not so efficient code but in a different way:

```py
import numpy as np

s = 5
H = np.zeros((s, s))

for c in range(s):
    for r in range(s):
        H[c, r] = 1 / (c + r + 1)

print(H)
```